# Providing IDs for batch requesting

Tags: api-design

I am designing an API and I want to allow the clients to be able to create several resources at once.  A client can POST an Order that has several Items.

One approach would be to allow the client give unique ids at the Order level and for each of the items levels, and me storing those (as well as our internal ones), but that would allow the client to request based on its ids. Example of request:

```
{
  order_ref: 'XXX',
  items: [
  { item_ref: 'xx', quantity: 5 },
  { item_ref: 'yy', quantity: 5 },
  ]
}
```

The other approach is to return an id for the order and for each of the items, but that seems not escalable as an order can have a lot of items so the request could even timeout.  It would also mean that the return would need to be in order so they can match the returned ids with what they requested.

What is the approach that one should be taking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take your first approach, clients *must* create ids. Sometimes this is ok, but usually it's annoying for them. Unless the id is an intrinsic part of the thing that won't ever change, they're just going to have to come up with their own random id and store it in their own local database. If your clients want to be able to do this, this is the right approach. You should enforce uniqueness across their generated ids by resource type, and just use those in your database.

Otherwise, the second approach is preferable because annoying your clients is bad for business. Yes, it's going to scale poorly if they add a thousand new items, but the response won't be that much larger than the request, since you're just adding 'id' properties in the response.

Comment: My main concern with second approach is that when creating all the resources from a request, it might timeout (because there can be a lot of them). How do you usually deal with this scenario? Do you put limits? If you have any resources where I can educate myself on this, I would appreciate.

Comment: Make the POST asynchronous. Create some kind of status endpoint, such as /pendingOrders. Reply to the POST right away with a Location header set to /pendingOrders/{id}, and a body containing a guess as to when the request might be complete. Clients can GET /pendingOrders/{id} which will give them the status of the order generation. Eventually, the order will be complete, and the GET response can contain a URI to the new order in the system.

Comment: But if that "order" is creating several resources, how do they know which one is which?

Comment: The same way they would if it was in the original response. Have the order maintain the items in the order they were submitted. The client will need to go back and forth to match them up, but that would happen anyway.